# Need help in identification of formula

Tags: energy, radiation

[image: this equatio was just randomly given without any description]

i would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide me with the concept to learn about this equation

Comment: this image was just randomly given without any explanation about it ... it would sufficient enough to just tell me what it is ...

Comment: Do you have _any_ context at all about this? There are some odd symbols in there. The capital M (for mass one would use lower case m), the "is an element of" symbol ($\in$) that looks a bit like an epsilon (should it be $\epsilon_0$, perhaps? Or $E$ for energy?)

Comment: It loks a bit like the equation for a de Broglie wavelength, if $\sqrt{2Mk\epsilon}$ can be interpreted as a momentum.

Comment: Can you tell us *where* you found this formula.

Answer (score 8):

Is it possible the:

[image: symbol]

is *ke* meaning *kinetic energy*? I ask because the equation for the [de Broglie wavelength](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/debrog2.html) of a non-relativistic particle is:

$$ \lambda = \frac{h}{\sqrt{2m_0 KE}} $$

where $KE$ is the particle's kinetic energy.

Comment: I think you nailed it. Removing my answer as it's now redundant / superseded by this -better- answer.